# Where are the Erlang libraries?

Tags: erlang

Does Erlang have libraries? Like math or stdio, from the C language. Where can they be found?

Answer (score 12):

**Updated**: [A boat load of them](http://erldocs.com/).

Comment: And at to the second part of the Q as to where they can be found then that depends on your installation. Default location is `/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib`. But since you never need to "include" them like in C you really don't need to worry about that.

Comment: @jldupont Wow, a boatload of 404's. *Sigh*

Answer (score 5):

If You want to "locate" them You can use

```
code:root_dir().
```

or

```
code:lib_dir().
```

to "find" them...

Answer (score 4):

Also, for all libraries, not available in standard distribution, you can use Agner: http://erlagner.org

Answer (score 2):

You can allways install any library you need, compile, and point the enviroment ERL_LIBS var to it, example ..

```
mkdir ~/my_erlang_libs
cp my_wonderfull_erlang_lib ~/my_erlang_libs
export ERL_LIBS=~/my_erlang_libs
```

Regards.